# Custom luminous letters in terminal?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, debian

I saw this screenshot in my university book, is it possible to make something similar to this in gnome terminal?
I'm not sure it's screenshot and not a photo though, but it seems more like screenshot to me.

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19aUf.png)

Comment: `cool-retro-term` provides the capacity to emulate old visual-display-units, including fonts & ability to have characters burn into the screen (ie. phosphor burn-in etc).  You can install with `snap install cool-retro-term` on all Ubuntu products & releases.

Comment: You've marked your question as a Debian-Ubuntu workflow issue? or packaging problem for Ubuntu; how does that relate? given you've made no reference to what you're trying to package for use in Ubuntu (or upstream to Debian & flow back to Ubuntu)  Why your tags?

Comment: If you're NOT after the "glow" effect on characters, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code might be interesting. Note also that these generally might work only in a specific environment e.g. gnome-shell / xterm and no other. Reading up on "terminfo", "ncurses" and the "tput" command might help in those situations.

Comment: Not "luminous", but a black background, and white and yellow **bold** characters. Read `man console_codes`